# Proving the sup and inf of $S$

Tags: real-analysis

Let there be a set of all numbers in the form $2^{-p}+3^{-q}+5^{-r}$ where $p,q,r$ each take on all positive integer (say this is set $S$). I know that the $\mbox{sup } S = \frac{31}{30}$ and $\mbox{inf } S = 0$, but how would I go about proving this?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$2^{-p}\le {1\over 2}\\3^{-q}\le {1\over 3}\\5^{-r}\le {1\over 5}$$and $$2^{-p}+3^{-q}+5^{-r}\to 0\quad,\quad p,q,r\to \infty$$

Comment: How would you go about proving the $\mbox{sup } E$ (or Greatest Lower Bound) without using limits (or anything in calculus)?

Comment: This is because $31\over30$ is a member of this set and all other members always fall below it. Actually, $31\over30$ is the maximum of the set.

Comment: How would go about proving the $\mbox{inf } E= 0$ without using limits?

Comment: All of the terms of the set are positive and there exists a set subsequence in the set tending to $0$.

Comment: "All of the terms of the set are positive and there exists a set subsequence in the set tending to 0." Is there a well known proposition that claims the $\inf$ of a set of positive terms and a subseq $\to 0$ will be $0$?  Also, doesn't this use limits?  And can we actually claim $2^{-p}+3^{-q}+5^{-r}\to 0\quad,\quad p,q,r\to \infty$ without verification?

Comment: If you want to prove that the $inf$ is zero, you may do it by contradiction. Assume some positive value $l$ stands for the infimum of the set. Show that for any $l>0$, there exist terms of the set that fall below $l$. And surely, you can arbitrarily accept $2^{-p}\to 0$ when $p\to\infty$ by intuition

Answer (score 0):

Well, $0 < 2^{-p} \le \frac 12$ and $0 < 3^{-q} \le \frac 13$ and $0 < 5^{-r} < \frac 15$ so

$0 <  2^{-p}+3^{-q}+5^{-r} \le \frac 12 + \frac 13 + \frac 15=\frac{31}{30}$

So $E = \{2^{-p}+3^{-q}+5^{-r} \}$ is bounded below by $0$ and above by $\frac{31}{30}$

As $\frac{31}{30} \in E$ then any $y < \frac{31}{30}$ is not an upper bound so $\sup E = \frac {31}{30}$.  (If you haven't proven it yet you should prove that if an upper bound, $s$, of $S$ is an element of $s$ then $\sup S = \max S = s$.)

$0 \not \in E$ so we can't make that argument.

But if $y > 0$ can we prove $y$ is not a lower bound?  In other words can we prove if $y > 0$ then there exist $p, q,r\in \mathbb N$ so that $2^{-p} +3^{-q} + 5^{-r} < y$?

And we can.

Let's see... we can safely assume $1 > y> 0$.  Let $N > \log_2 \frac 1y > 0$.  If $p > N$ then $2^p > \frac 1y$ and $y > 2^{-p} $.

Now let $y_1 = y- 2^{-p} > 0$.  Let $N_1 > \log_3 \frac 1{y_1}$ so if $q > N_1$ we have $y_1 > 3^{-q} $.

Let $y_2 = y_1 - 3^{-q} = y - 2^{-p} - 3^{-q} > 0$.  Let $N_2 > \log_5 \frac 1{y_2}$ so if $r > N_2$ we have $y_2 > 5^{-r} $

So $y_2 - 5^{-r} = y - 2^{-p} - 3^{-q}-5^{-r} > 0$ and $y >  2^{-p}+ 3^{-q}+5^{-r}$.

So $y$ is not a lower bound.

So $0 = \inf E$.